# Grep Command Error

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have used grep command to filter the file based on the list.

`grep -w -F -f list.txt file1.tsv > file2.tsv`

But it is giving me some extra lines as well. Like there are 2130 values in my list while there are 2213 unique lines in file2. Here are first few lines of file1.

```
  Variant         Gene              
  rs1042714       ADRB2                  
  rs2297480       FDPS        
  rs12248560      CYP2C19
```

Here are some lines of List.txt.

```
rs228729
rs228642
rs228666
rs2640909
```

What should I use to filter the file based on list file?

Comment: The command is correct. The result means that some values from *list* appear multiple times in *file1*

Comment: Upload list.txt and file1.tsv somewhere and add links to your question.

Comment: there are no values which are appearing multiple times from list in file1  as I have removed duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is correct, To check your command :

```
grep -w -F -f list.txt file1.tsv > file2.tsv
```

execute the same command with `-v` to invert match :

```
grep -v -w -F -f list.txt file1.tsv > file2.tsv.invert
```

Check content of file2.tsv.invert

Test using your file (All results are ok ) :

```
grep -w -F -f list.txt file2.tsv.invert | wc -l
> 0 # it's ok

wc -l file2.tsv.invert file2.tsv # total must be equal to file1.tsv
> 2544 file2.tsv.invert
> 2997 file2.tsv
> 5541 total

wc -l file1.tsv
> 5541 file1.tsv
```

All seems OK !

Comment: Total lines of file2.tsv and file2.tsv are exceeding total of file1.tsv.  I have done total after removing duplicates. When I check both files on excel there are some value which are present both in file2.tsv and file2.tsv.invert

Comment: Have you DOS file ? try dos2unix to convert them if you need.

Comment: try to upload file somewhere

Comment: These are links of list and file1.    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rRN_hSAtlIx2afQGJjKVvu-aUp8mEkwU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gOEod8_daE-BljzTztJFwDr0WUL5xK0Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: All seems ok. give an exemple of invalid result (indicate a value).

Comment: I have highlighted few value found in output of grep but absent in list by red color https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O02xdpVTmCL4TihqcOteGlHBaHG-o0Ao/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `rs1024323` is not present in `list.txt`, 1 line in original file `file1.tsv`, no line in `file2.tsv` and 1 line in `file2.tsv.invert` ==> all is OK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158867/discussion-between-sarah-and-indent).